# Pagebreak between tables doesn't work

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using Jasper to create a report that contains two tables. Each table is in it's own Detail band. The problem is that sometimes the second table starts midpage orsometimes the title is displayed at the end of the page and it's table starts at the new page.

To counter this problem I added a page break in the detail band of the first table at the end of the first table believing that this would easily solve my problem but I'm still not getting a new page when the second table starts. This is the source that is getting generated from Jaspersoft Studio.

```
<band>
  Title and table
<break>
    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="134" width="93" height="1" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
    </reportElement>
</break>
</band>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It should be <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/> not <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>

Answer (score 1):

It should be `<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>` Please replace "com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" with "com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y"

Comment: How it can helps with pagebreak?

Comment: I'll try it out but this jrxml was created from Jaspersoft Studio, I didn't create the jrxml by hand.

Comment: how about manual modifying the source code and see the result. Good luck.